# Selenium Headless Tests running very slow on EC2 instance

Tags: docker, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, headless

Thanks for reading my post. I've got a problem that I'd like to pick your brains about. I have many automated Selenium tests that are written in Java. They leverage JUnit for testing. I am tasked with optimizing the run time of these tests on an Amazon EC2 CentOS server. The tests are pulled from a Github repository and get stored inside a Docker Container on the EC2 instance. Similarly, these tests also run from the client's laptop through Eclipse using Cucumber. On the laptop, the tests take a fraction of the time that they do on the EC2 instance. The EC2 instance and laptop have the same amount of RAM and plenty of CPU processing power to run the tests, so I would think that the tests on the EC2 instance wouldn't take nearly as long as they do. Both the EC2 instance and the laptop have to go through a proxy to get to the Internet as well. I have made sure this part was set up correctly, as I had to set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and no_proxy to specific IP addresses.

In this section, I will provide the code that the chromedriver gets instantiated with whenever it is called. I will also provide the exact commands that I am using to run the tests. Please see below:

Here is the method that is called when it gets instantiated:

```
public static ChromeOptions setupChromeOptions() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> p refs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
    options.setHeadless(true);
    options.setProxy(null);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");   
    options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server=");
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");  
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1280,720");
    return options;
}
```

Here are the commands that are ran through Jenkins on the EC2 instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/Git/REPOS_NAME                                                            # Navigate to where the repos are at on the EC2.
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull                                                                                    # Pull down the latest.
sudo docker container ls                                                                    # Display the running containers.
sudo docker exec 0967d39b1967 bash -c 'cd /Selenium/ ; rm -rf REPO_ROOT_FOLDER/ ; exit'     # Delete the automated test folder so that it gets copied over fresh.
sudo docker cp /home/ec2-user/Git/REPO_NAME/REPO_ROOT_FOLDER 0967d39b1967:/Selenium/        # Copy the latest from the Github Repository to the Docker container.
sudo docker exec 0967d39b1967 bash -c 'cd /Selenium/REPO_ROOT_FOLDER/ANOTHER_FOLDER/driver ; chmod 0777 chromedriver ; cd .. ; mvn clean test'  # Activate the Testrunner that is enabled in pom.xml. This kicks off the automated tests.
```

Finally, here are the version numbers and OS details of what I'm running:

```
Amazon EC2: CentOS 6.10
Docker Container OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Selenium: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
Chromedriver: 84.0.4147.30
Google Chrome: 84.0.4147.105
Java: OpenJDK 1.8.0_252
Cucumber: 2.0.0
I cannot provide links to an HTML Page that I'm scraping because it's all inside of a Salesforce environment.

EC2 Specs:

AWS T2.XLarge
4 vCPUs
64-Bit
16 GB RAM
54 CPU Credits per hour

Laptop Specs:

Intel Core i7-8665U @ 1.90GHz, 2112 MHz, 4 cores, 8 Logocal Processors
16 GB RAM
Windows 10
```

```
Group of Tests 1:
EC2: 50 minutes
Laptop through Eclipse: 20 minutes

Group of Tests 2:
EC2: 2 hours 43 minutes
Laptop through Eclipse: 1 hour 15 minutes
```

There are two breakdowns of the timings for two groups of tests. As you can see, the times off of the EC2 are much longer than that of that laptop.

Finally, here is a log of the set of tests that take 50 minutes to run. I had to change some of the directory and path names to protect the client.

```
Started by user Scott-IM
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on EC2_INSTANCE in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Run mvn test
[Run mvn test] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins166122467778007381.sh
Fetching origin
FIPS mode initialized
HEAD is now at 506f4ef Setting proxy to null for Chromeoptions
FIPS mode initialized
Already up to date.
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0967d39b1967        IMAGE_NAME          "/Selenium/setup.sh"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   CONTAINER_NAME
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< test:automation >--------------
[INFO] Building test-automation 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ automation ---
[INFO] Deleting /Selenium/automation/automation/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ automation ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Selenium/automation/automation/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ automation ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ automation ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ automation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 111 source files to /Selenium/salesforce-automation/salesforce-automation/target/test-classes
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/mapper/OIDP_Flow/OIDP_Email_Auto_Approval_Flow_2.java:[797,128] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/mapper/OIDP_Flow/OIDP_Email_Auto_Approval_Flow_2.java:[1842,130] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/shared/ExtentReporter.java:[126,33] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/shared/ExtentReporter.java:[127,32] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/mapper/rsiaa/HD_ISO_VSC_Auto_Approval_of_Resubmitted_Si.java:[4977,95] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/pages/aao/TrackingRecord.java:[27,39] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/pages/aao/TrackingRecord.java:[117,84] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/pages/aao/TrackingRecord.java:[156,92] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/com/test/pages/aao/TrackingRecord.java:[195,84] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/restApiPOC/PrivacyRestApiConnection.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Selenium/automation/automation/src/test/java/restApiPOC/PrivacyRestApiConnection.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ automation ---
[WARNING] The parameter forkMode is deprecated since version 2.14. Use forkCount and reuseForks instead.
 
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Running com.test.runner.TestRunner2
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 23815
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1604696323.888][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Nov 06, 2020 8:58:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Frame count :3
Frame count :4
Frame count :6
Newly Generated Service Item Number is :15355359
Frame count :3
Frame count :3
Clicked on new service item :15355359
Frame count :2
Frame count :2
Frame count :4
Frame count :3
Frame count :3
 
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
33 Steps (33 passed)
44m57.274s
 
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2,698.236 sec - in com.salesforcetest.runner.TestRunner2
 
Results :
 
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-06T21:43:40Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If anything was unclear or didn't make sense, please let me know and I will address the issue. I have looked all over the Internet for solutions and haven't found anything yet. I'm almost at a loss of what to do, as I'm not entirely sure what the exact cause of the slowness is. If anyone could provide some clues or things to try, I would be more than willing to give it a shot.

Thanks much for any and all help.

Comment: When you measure the time it takes to run on this on the client's laptop, are you also taking into account the git fetch and the docker setup time?  or are you simply counting the time it takes to 'run tests'?  Something to keep in mind, subsequent runs of a docker image that already exists will always be much faster because it doesn't have to go fetch the image again.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so soon. To answer your question, I am not. The Docker instance doesn't get remade every time the tests are ran. I use the same Docker Container over and over again until there is a need to create a new one. I normally only destroy the Container if I need to spin up a new one for some reason, or there is a potential fix I am trying out. Additionally, cloning the repository where the tests are stored only takes about 1 minute and 20 seconds on the laptop. So I don't think pulling from Github every time is causing the slowness.

Comment: So what other differences are left to examine? Cucumber? java version? Chrome version?  OS?  Python version? Possibly processor type? 

Do you have actual timing breakdowns overall, vs per test, etc?  I'm curious what the magnitude is?

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the details you're asking about. Cucumber actually isn't used on the EC2 side, since there is no visual front end UI. It's just used in the Eclipse side of things so that the developers of the tests can see them running. I'm not using Python either. I have running times for various groups of tests, but not anything more than that.

Comment: How much time overall vs how many tests are we talking?

Comment: I've added a breakdown of the timings to the original post. Please see above.

Comment: Yeah, more than double the time. Any chance you're running the tests twice on the ec2?

Comment: I do not believe so. I am only calling "mvn clean test" once, so I would think that this would be the only time it actually gets ran.

Comment: Do you have the timings per test?  Does each test result show the nearly double duration?

Comment: What I provided in the original post is all of the metrics I currently have. I just went into Jenkins and looked at the total job run time, which is where I got the EC2 values from. The laptop times came from the developer of the tests themselves when he runs them off of his laptop. Is there a way to check to see if Selenium is running the tests twice?

Comment: Only way I know would be to look at the log of the test runner or output from the tests.

Comment: I have modified my original post to include the log of the set of tests that take 50 minutes to run on the EC2 instance. Please see above.

Comment: So I noticed you have 0 tests run.  This would suggest you aren't breaking up your actions into individual test results?  Do I read that correctly?  If so, there isn't much you can do to know what's going on unless you turn on selenium logging.  (Which I find is a pain to read). But I think it would be worthwhile to turn it on in both environments and see if it tells you anything about what's happening.  That, or maybe try adding debug logging in your test scripts.

Comment: I don't know maven very well, does it give you timing of each step separately?

Comment: So the reason why it's showing 0 tests ran is because those numbers are gathered from JUnit. We are only using JUnit for its tags, not for it's reporting. We're using Extent Reports to create reports. What I typically look for is the number of Scenarios and Steps Passed, not Tests Ran. Does this clear things up any more?

Comment: It does.  Ultimately you want to look for timing differences per test.  Each test is double the time on EC2 vs if one or a handful of tests are taking much longer than expected.  If it's only certain tests, you'd then have to look at THOSE tests to figure out why they are slow.  If it's ALL the tests, then we are looking for something perhaps system wide like a difference between chromdrivers, etc.

Comment: did you ever figure out why the tests on the EC2 were slower?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution per se, but throwing some things out there worth trying.

Since you're comparing Chrome run times I would advise trying to keep the versions in sync.  That's tough on windows because you often have no control when Chrome updates.  This isn't to say it would solve your problem but it would help eliminate a variable.
Chrome (and chromedriver for that matter) goes through a decent amount of changes that not being on the same version CAN and HAS made a difference for me.

Here are a few of the chrome options I've had to resort to using over the past couple years to get things running smoothly. I noticed 3 you didn't have.

`--disable-extensions` -- You never know what they might have on their local version of chrome.

`--dns-prefetch-disable` -- script would hang without this in older versions of chromedriver. 
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402#c128

`--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess` -- script freezing 
 [https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chromedriver-users/ktp-s_0M5NM[21-40]](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chromedriver-users/ktp-s_0M5NM%5B21-40%5D)

Comment: I'll try these additional Chrome options and get back to you with updated run times.

Comment: I added the additional options as you had suggested, and the runtime did not improve at all. Although I set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and no_proxy, do you think I need to set --proxy-server to the same IP and port as well? I noticed that when I get rid of all of the proxy options, Selenium cannot log into Salesforce. The login history shows no attempt of a log in. However, if I add the proxy options as I have specified in my original post, I get logged in. Additionally, if I try to use --proxy-auto-detect, it fails to log in as well.

Comment: I don't know. My environment doesn't use a proxy for testing so I can't help there.

Comment: Hey Scott - Just curious to know if you have found a solution already for this. Because i face the same issue when running the selenium tests on an aws fargate. 
The tests take 2-3 times more on aws.

Comment: No I didn't unfortunately.

Comment: @Scott-IM any chance you tried running the docker containers locally?  if so, was there any noticeable time difference?